# Can TFS 2010 generate an e-mail alert when an item has been checked out for longer than 'X' days?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

If a user checks out a file and fails to check it back in after a certain number of days, I'd like TFS 2010 to generate an e-mail. (For example, the user would be notified after the item has been checked out for 1 day, and the entire team notified after 2 days.)

I found the article about writing [TFS server plugins](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/assafstone/archive/2011/07/29/how-to-write-a-robust-tfs-server-plugin-with-job-extensions.aspx)

but I was wondering if there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that notifications/alerts are event triggered in TFS. So if nothing changes there will be no trigger.
A little bit easier than writing your own plugin, which also requires a trigger, but can check for more than the changed item, a small application would be easier. A small command line tool is enough and you could run it by using scheduled tasks once a day. The tool would check for all pending changes and how long they are pending and if they are to old, it will send a mail to the user.

Comment: Thank you. We are going to look into creating a SQL job to accomplish it.

Comment: Working directly on the database is not supported by Microsoft. I would suggest to use the API, which offers you functionalities to directly get information about pending changes and who is the owner of the change.